# How to avoid calling a method multiple times when the method takes long time to complete

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

There are several view controllers in my app where I need to sync the local contents with server using a method running in a background thread. Sometimes I need to insert data to  my database on server if user has created any. The approach I am using here is to set a flag(something like isSynced = NO) on objects that I need to sync with server (there objects are in Core Data). When the syncing is complete my method will get rid of the flag(e.g. isSynced = YES) so it won't be sent again next time.

Now the problems is that the syncing method takes very long to complete(1 or 2seconds.). If now user pops out this particular view controller and swiftly comes back the previous call is still in progress and next one will be kicked off. The consequence is that there might be duplication in database.

My approach now is the make the syncing method to be called by a Singleton object:

```
 
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSyncing; 

//every time before syncing. check if object is available for syncing

if (!isSyncing) {

  isSyncing = YES;
  // sync server 

  // when complete
  isSyncing = NO; 

  // post notification to view controller to reload table

} else {

  // cancel because previous call is not finished

}
```

My concern is that if the call is cancelled my view controller will not be able to receive the notification is waiting for. I can fix this by posting another notification in the event of cancelation. I am wondering if this is the right to do this because I think that this problem should be pretty common in iOS development and there should be a standard way to deal with it

Comment: Use `isSyncing` in your singleton seems fine to me.and you can use `NSFetchedResultsController` also to watch coreData changing sense you need to reload a tableview,so you do not need to send notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton approach may not be necessary.  I don't see the harm in sending a database insert for each new object. You will still need to ensure each object is synched.  That is, update the "isSynched" flag. Keep each object that needs to be synced in a "need to synch" list.

Then, update the "isSynced" flag by performing a background query on the database to check if the object exits.  Then, use the result of the query to set the isSynched flag.

If the query result indicates the object is not in the database you then resend the object and leave it's "isSynced" flag set to NO.

If the query result indicates the object is in the database, set the "isSynced" flag to YES and remove it from your "need to synch" list.

An approach for preventing duplicate database entries is to make a unique key.  For example, tag each with a hash based on the time and date. Then configure the table to ensure each key is unique.